# Question on Latest Spanning Issue For Rows on Html Tables

Tags: html-table

I found as of 2021 Chrome, Mozilla, Edge, and Opera browsers are changing the layout of table spanning structure on rows.  My old table structure would make my list look neat when the rows were not stretched to adjust to a previous spanned row in the table.  Now the un-spanned rows will stretch vertically to the previous spanned row size, (In this case I have the first row spanned at 7 rows. Doesn't look nice for text being spaced in the rows of the following un-spanned rows. (The rows in the un-spanned rows now stretch vertically to adjust the the first row spanned at 7 rows).

By the way, Firefox was the only browser doing this in previous years, now it appears they are all adopting this new table row stretching method.

Is There a method of coding to not have the rows vertically expanding to adjust to the spanned row?

I understand this may sound confusing so I would like to show what I am trying to explain in pictures.

[Here Is A Detailed Layout of What I am Trying To Explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZnRt.jpg)

This may also expand a bit more on what's going on from google:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/16PFD1GtMI9Zgwu0jtPaKZJ75Q2wyZ9EZnVbBacOfiNA/edit

```
here is an updated simplified generic html table showing the images I presented..

        <html>
        <head>
          <title>Table Row Spanning - Previous vs Current Browsers Row Stretching look</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <table style="width: 500px; height: 200px">
            <tr style="border: 1px; color:#000000; white-space:nowrap; border-size: 1px; background: #66FF00; border: #000000; height:5px">
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;Column 1</td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;Column 2</td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;Column 3</td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;Column 4</td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;Column 5</td>
            </tr>
            <td  rowspan = "7" style="border: 1px; color:#000000; white-space:nowrap; border-size: 1px; background: #66FF00; border: #000000; height:10px">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;Spanned 7 Rows</td>
                <td style="border: 1px; color:#000000; white-space:nowrap; border-size: 1px; background: #66FF00; border: #000000; height:20px">&nbsp;&nbsp;row 1</td>
                <td style="&nbsp;&nbsp;border: 1px; color:#000000; white-space:nowrap; border-size: 1px; background: #66FF00; border: #000000; height:20px">row 1</td>
                <td style="border: 1px; color:#000000; white-space:nowrap; border-size: 1px; background: #66FF00; border: #000000; height:20px">&nbsp;&nbsp;row 1</td>
                <td style="border: 1px; color:#000000; white-space:nowrap; border-size: 1px; background: #66FF00; border: #000000; height:20px">&nbsp;&nbsp;row 1</td>
            </td>
            <tr style="border: 1px; color:#000000; white-space:nowrap; border-size: 1px; background: #66FF00; border: #000000; height:20px; padding-left:10px">
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;row 2</td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;row 2</td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;row 2</td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;row 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="border: 1px; color:#000000; white-space:nowrap; border-size: 1px; background: #66FF00; border: #000000; height:20px; padding-left:10px">
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;row 3</td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;row 3</td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;row 3</td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;row 3</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Please show the code that you are trying to use to set this up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a 4th row where the new `<tr>` has *no specified height*. Then the table's extra height all goes to this new row. This is your code with just one line added.

```html
        <table style="width: 500px; height: 200px">
            <tr style="border: 1px; color:#000000; white-space:nowrap; border-size: 1px; background: #66FF00; border: #000000; height:5px">
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;Column 1</td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;Column 2</td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;Column 3</td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;Column 4</td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;Column 5</td>
            </tr>
            <td  rowspan = "7" style="border: 1px; color:#000000; white-space:nowrap; border-size: 1px; background: #66FF00; border: #000000; height:10px">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;Spanned 7 Rows</td>
                <td style="border: 1px; color:#000000; white-space:nowrap; border-size: 1px; background: #66FF00; border: #000000; height:20px">&nbsp;&nbsp;row 1</td>
                <td style="&nbsp;&nbsp;border: 1px; color:#000000; white-space:nowrap; border-size: 1px; background: #66FF00; border: #000000; height:20px">row 1</td>
                <td style="border: 1px; color:#000000; white-space:nowrap; border-size: 1px; background: #66FF00; border: #000000; height:20px">&nbsp;&nbsp;row 1</td>
                <td style="border: 1px; color:#000000; white-space:nowrap; border-size: 1px; background: #66FF00; border: #000000; height:20px">&nbsp;&nbsp;row 1</td>
            <tr style="border: 1px; color:#000000; white-space:nowrap; border-size: 1px; background: #66FF00; border: #000000; height:20px; padding-left:10px">
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;row 2</td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;row 2</td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;row 2</td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;row 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="border: 1px; color:#000000; white-space:nowrap; border-size: 1px; background: #66FF00; border: #000000; height:20px; padding-left:10px">
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;row 3</td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;row 3</td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;row 3</td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;row 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td style="outline: solid;">I added this</td></tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Genius!  That actually works for me!  My original coding for the table is much more complex using php variables with mysqli while loop etc ..  but this solves the issue I had with the rows expanding vertical..  Thank You!    It appears that by you adding that last row in the table and not specifying the height it absorbs the excess spacing.. Is that correct?

Comment: That's correct. I forgot the exact order that the excess table height is distributed to various types of rows, but unconstrained rows get excess height before fixed height rows.

Comment: Thanks dgrogan, I spent much time and research trying to resolved this since the browsers have updated this method of row stretching.  Much appreciated!